# Error in cvMerge and cvShowImage using C interface

Tags: c, opencv

This is the code i am using for display image using C interface in opencv

```
        IplImage * mSrcImg = cvLoadImage("C:\\test.jpg");
        IplImage * mOutImg;
        vector<IplImage*> b , g ,r;

        cvSplit(&mSrcImg , &b , &g , &r , NULL);
        cvEqualizeHist(&b, &b);
        cvEqualizeHist(&g, &g);
        cvEqualizeHist(&r, &r);

        cvMerge(&b, &g, &r, NULL, &mOutImg );

        cvShowImage("Image" , mOutImg);
        cvWaitKey();
```

but getting runtime error in it.

Error

```
Bad argument (unknown array type) in unknown function , file ......source\matrix.cpp line 698
```

Comment: Could you show the error messages?

Comment: @GoldRoger its the line number in matrix.cpp library

Comment: your 1st line, and the last 2 are correct. (anything else is broken)

Comment: hhm i think i need to create the image and give a size to `mOutImg`

Comment: Retagged `c++`, this isn't C.

Comment: +1 (also you have to release that afterwards)

Comment: @dreamlax it's opencv's dreaded c-api, not c++

Comment: ahmad, neither cvSplit nor cvMerge work on vectors, but IplImage* and you'll have to create/release each f**cking single one of them. why insist on using a horribly outdated api that keeps biting you ?

Comment: I was just trying to convert the code of c++ interface in c interface , just as a practice , okay lemme leave it :P

Comment: @berak: The problem that OP is facing is because he is passing C++ objects to a C API. The API may be in C, but the problem is through the use of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you necessary to use C api refer below, which will do the same as above,

```
IplImage*src=0,*bgr,*b,*g,*r;
src = cvLoadImage("Flower.jpg",1);
bgr = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 3 ) ;
b = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 );
g = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 );
r = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 1 ) ;

cvSplit(src, b, g, r, 0 );
cvEqualizeHist( b, b );
cvEqualizeHist( g, g );
cvEqualizeHist( r, r );
cvMerge(b,g,r,0,bgr);

cvNamedWindow("source");
cvShowImage("source",src);
cvNamedWindow("hsv");
cvShowImage("hsv",bgr);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Also see the same in C++ interface,

```
 Mat src=imread("Flower.jpg",1);
 Mat bgr[3];
 split(src,bgr);
 equalizeHist(bgr[0],bgr[0]);
 equalizeHist(bgr[1],bgr[1]);
 equalizeHist(bgr[2],bgr[2]);

 Mat dst;
 merge(bgr,3,dst);
 imshow("src",src);
 imshow("dst",dst);
 waitKey();
```